# VBA rodando o python - Script nao faz nada

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, vba, script

Boa tarde, tenho um comando em VBA chamando um script especifico do Python.
O que ocorre é que se eu rodar o script manualmente, ele funciona perfeitamente, sem problema algum. Rodando pelo VBA ele so da o primeiro comando de Print e nada mais.

Código VBA:

```
Sub RunPython()
    Dim PythonScript As String
    Dim args As String
    Dim wsh As Object: Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    PythonScript = """C:\Users\lgfrota\Desktop\Teste\StaticTest2.py"""
    args = "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.py"    
    Shell "C:\Python27\python.exe" & " " & args & " -r " & PythonScript
End Sub
```

Código Python:

```
lista = []
for file
name in os.listdir('.'):
  if ".dat" in filename:
    lista.append(filename)
    print filename
print lista
for i in range(len(lista)):  
  #Fazer coisas
print(ag,fx,fy,fz,mx,my,mz)
  resultsnam = [ag, fx, fy, fz, mx, my, mz]
  for rnam in resultsnam:
    file.write(rnam.center(19, " ")+"|")
  file.write("\n"*3)
```

Lembrando que o arquivo funciona perfeitamente quando rodado separadamente.

---

obs: O print Filename funciona porem rodado manualmente ele responde todas os arquivos corretos da pasta. Rodando pelo vba, a resposta é:

```
Custom Office Templates
desktop.ini
My Music
My Pictures
My Videos
```

Comment: O seu VBA está iniciando o python na pasta do seu usuário `C:\Users\lgfrota\Documents`, e lá não tem nenhum arquivo `.dat`

Comment: Mesmo rodando o script numa pasta que possui esse .dat? Quando eu joguei o caminho completo no python, aparentemente funcionou perfeitamente. Estou tentando resolver agora, a forma de fazer o python pegar o filepath como argumento entregue pelo VBA

Comment: A pasta onde o script está não importa; O que importa é a pasta que o VBA está considerando como "atual".